# How to build/run a java project on linux system using bash?

Tags: java, linux, bash

So I have a java project in intellij right now. I'm trying to get it to run through ssh on a linux system.

I've uploaded the class files, however  The project will not run unless I take out all the package declarations and rebuild the project.

Whats the correct way to build/run a java project using bash?

Comment: That depends on how it was built.  Is there a specific driver class that only houses a main method?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how you are moving the files? Are you moving the files along with the folders? How are you trying to run it? If, for example, you have Test.java declared in package test, then Test.class must reside at test/Test.class

Comment: Easiest approach from the deployment perspective is to have your build system generate a "uberjar" with all dependencies built in (see http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/uberjar/), such that you can just run `java -jar your.jar`.

Comment: I've copied the entire project along with the package folders. however I do not know how to use javac to compile it using the package folders

Answer (score 0):

The only way to run a java program is to call the [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) command-line.

To build it is javac but if you hae uploaded the class files, it means that it is already compiled

Comment: Yes, but running it does not work. I need a way to run with packages

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have a entry main method in one of your java file, then use java xxxx -cp yourjarpaths to start your program. You can also use ant or maven to start your project, in bash, you can run "ant xxx" or "maven xxxx" to start the jvm

Comment: is the path to the jar, or class files? also is cp relative?

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the command line to build and run the java programs using [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) and [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) commands, you should consider using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or any other build manager for your project. This will be especially useful when you start having external dependencies in your projects.